# Pre-official adoption years

Tags: records, england, 20th-century, adoption

If a child born at England in 1914 was placed in foster care and stayed with their foster family, wouldn't that child somehow have to prove their identity when they started work? For example, they would have needed a national insurance number, right?

Are there any records available for national insurance registration?

Answer (score 3):

*Caveat* - I don't know the answer but the current situation *in the UK* is this:

According to [the HMRC site - especially see "What happens when you apply for a National Insurance number"](http://www.hmrc.gov.uk/ni/intro/number.htm), you should auto receive a National insurance Number when you are 16 (I doubt that happened back then - I can't see how they would know such a child existed in the days before Child Benefit). If not, you have to apply, and you have to provide your birth or adoption certificate or other evidence of identity. That's what happens *now*. For the life of me, I cannot remember how I got mine. It was certainly pre-1st-Child-Benefit.

Logically, there is absolutely no way that any records for NINo registration of someone born less than 100y ago would be open to any sort of enquiry.

There is, incidentally, the details for the [1939 National Identity Card](http://www.1911census.org.uk/1939.htm) that are a/v under Freedom of Information requests - for which you do not always need to provide an address. Beyond confirmation of birth-date, this *might not* be much use for your specific task. Incidentally, the authorities have to check that anyone they provide on your response is dead, so you may get a "bonus" death date as part of the response, as well as the 1939 data.

Comment: You don't always need the address to get details from the 1939 National identity card. And (because they have to check that all the individuals they provide information on are dead) you may get a bonus "death date" for somebody, as I did, as well as the information collected in 1939.

Comment: @ColeValleyGirl - thanks for that. I've edited my response to include your comments. It's not a document I'm familiar with as I've never had a family in my tree where the Id Card data seemed to be any potential use, according to my understanding of it. You have at least confirmed for me that all people on the response have to be dead, which means it's no real use for confirming children born btw 1911 and 1939! Some, but not all, would appear.